# getPosition() on google maps is changing repeatedly

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

```
      $('<div/>').addClass('centerMarker').appendTo(map.getDiv())
      var mp = $('.centerMarker');
     google.maps.event.addListener(mp.data('win'), 'position_changed', function(){
          var locations = mp.data('win').getPosition();
     });
```

Above code is working fine, but  `getPosition()` retirning data is changing frequently from `{H:'latdat',L:'Logdat'}`, to `{G:'latdat',K:'Logdat'}`

And today it is not returning the latitude and longitude. Is it a mistake from google side or from my side.

Answer (score 1):

I called it Incorrectly.

Below one is correct implementation

```
var lat = myMarker.getPosition().lat();

var lng = myMarker.getPosition().lng();
```

Previously if I do getPosition() i'm getting latitude and longitude. But it is not the correct way